# React Admin, how to get the Empty page feature, while having a "filterDefaultValues" tag in the <List>

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

As per the documentation of "React Admin", in the filter tag we cannot give "alwaysOn" and "defalutValue" at the same element.

In my case,
I need an filter element to be alwaysOn and with a default value,
so I am passing the "filterDefaultValues" at the , and always on in the 
**by this the Empty page feature is getting over ridden.**
I need the Empty page to be loading up. but not able to achieve this.

My filters -
Filter {...props} SelectInput source="StatusFlag" label="Status" choices={StatusFlags} alwaysOn

My List -
<List {...props} filters={} filterDefaultValues={{ StatusFlag: '1' }}
// empty={ } // nor the default empty page is working not the declared one, but i need it.

> 